# Convert SQL with 'is in' to QueryOver()

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I need the fallowing Query do with NHibernate QueryOver. But I have Problems with the List.

select * from contact where CountryId = 'xxx' and ContactTypeId in ('aaa', 'bbb')

The Values are Guid's. I have a List() which contains the Guid's for ContactTypeId (contactTypes)

I have tried - but this will not work:

```
                var query = contactRepository.GetAllOver()
                    .Where(x => x.Country != null && x.Country.Id == countryId)
                    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ContactType.Id).IsInG(contactTypes);
```

I hope someone could give me a tipp how to write this with QueryOver.

Comment: How about AndRestrictionOn(p => p.ContactType.Id).IsInG<Guid>(GuidList) Also what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var query = contactRepository.GetAllOver()
                .Where(x => x.Country != null && x.Country.Id == countryId)
                .And(Restrictions.On(c => c.ID).IsIn(contactTypes)
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I have solved it now with
var query = contactRepository.GetAllOver()
                .Where(x => x.Country != null && x.Country.Id == countryId)
                .AndRestrictionsOn(c => c.ID).IsIn(contactTypes)

I think, this is the same like your solution

Comment: @t.kehl: Yes, it's the same!!